# How can I do api calls (graphql) only from client on a static generated nuxt.js page?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I want to pick some additional data from a graqphql endpoint on a static page, generated by nuxt.js. How can I do this (Which hook is how to use)?

Edit, to be more concrete:
I have the following component, that should fetch the daily accurate exchangerate. This has not necessarily be done on page load. So I want to pick it, after the page has loaded. The pages are generated static pages and have a description component, that has this component:

```
<template>
  <strong :v-if="exchangerate.rate">
    / {{ exchangerate.currency }} {{ Math.round(price * exchangerate.rate).toLocaleString('en-US') }}
  </strong>
</template>

<script>
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag'

export default ({
  fetchOnServer: false,
  props: {
    price: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
      default: 'USD'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      exchangerate: {}
    }
  },
  async fetch ({ app }) {
    await app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
      query: gql`
        query getSpecificRateQuery($where: JSON) {
          exchangerates(where: $where) {
            currency
            rate
            updated_at
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        where: { currency: this.currency }
      }
    }).then(({ data }) => {
      const exchangerate = {}
      exchangerate.currency = data.exchangerates[0].currency
      exchangerate.rate = data.exchangerates[0].rate
      return { exchangerate }
    })
  }
})
</script>
```

`fetch()` seems not to work. The page shows "NaN".

Comment: if the question is how to do something only in the client side, you can use if(process.client){ ... }

Comment: This question is too vague. `fetch()` hook or any other that you're already using.

Comment: I did an edit to be more concrete.

Comment: I added this to call fetch, but got error 'this.$fetch is not a function': 
```mounted () {
    this.fetchRate()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchRate () {
      this.$fetch()
    }
  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked like expected:

```
<template>
  <strong v-if="!loading && exchangerates[0].rate">
    / {{ exchangerates[0].currency }} {{ Math.round(price * exchangerates[0].rate).toLocaleString('en-US') }}
  </strong>
</template>

<script>
import { getSpecificRateQuery } from '~/graphql/products-queries'

export default ({
  props: {
    price: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
      default: 'USD'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      loading: 0,
      exchangerates: [{ }]
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    $loadingKey: 'loading',
    exchangerates: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      prefetch: true,
      query: getSpecificRateQuery,
      variables () {
        return {
          where: { currency: this.currency }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

I had to set the caching to `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`, so the api is called everytime, also on navigating through browser history.
Also declaring an empty object in the exchangerates array `exchangerates: [{ }]` is important to prevent an undefined error.

('getSpecificRateQuery' is the same query as above.)

And I wrapped the component into `<client-only>` in the parent component:

```
<client-only>
  <PriceExchange currency="USD" :price="product.price" />
</client-only>
```